# Count max occurence of character in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Im looking to find the max amount of ! in a dataframe and im not 100% sure if i have the right code:

```
finefoods_df['Review'].max().count("!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.count` and *then* find its `max`:

```
finefoods_df['Review'].str.count('!').max()
```

---

**Demo**

```
df
         A
0      hi!
1  hello!!
2   bye!!!

df.A.str.count('!')

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

df.A.str.count('!').max()
3
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I had that before and just thought it looked weird and i missed .str first. I will accept this answer once i can

Comment: Woops my bad! There you go!

Comment: @J.McCraiton No worries, happy coding.